# CSS - "Return" transition not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add a CSS transition on the max-height property of an element, to make it look like it's opening and closing.
It's working properly on the opening part, but when I try to close it, it just skips the transition.

I tried applying the `"transition: max-height .5s ease-in"` line to the element in its opened state as with the closed state, but it doesn't change a thing.
I also tried transitioning the height property instead, but it doesn't change anything either.

Here's the demo, try with screen width below 992px: http://efficience4.com/laloupe/fiche-auteur.html (click on "lire la biographie")

Any ideas as to why it does this and how to fix it ? :)

Comment: Where is the button ' Lire la biographie ' ?

Comment: Sorry, just edited to be more precise ! It's showing on screens below 992px !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `ease-in` is causing that.

- Slow transition in, ends abruptly = `ease-in`.
- Begins abruptly, slow transition out = `ease-out`.

You may just want to use `ease` or `ease-in-out`.

Also, `max-height` should be a CSS property defined within the specified element.

Comment: oh yes, silly me. Thank you ! I'm going with ease-in-out. Any idea why the "out" transition has a delay ? I haven't specified any..

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Steve Ventimiglia, i removed ease-in. 
I still had a problem of delay when closing the div because of the max-height property.
I resolved this with this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27515933/7247523 
Basically, putting a delay of -.1s on the closing transition, and of 0s to the opening one.
Example :

```
#toggled{
    max-height: 0px;
    transition: max-height .8s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) -.1s;
}

#trigger:hover + #toggled{
    max-height: 9999px;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 1, 0); 
    transition-delay: 0s; 
}
```